# Manually load a lazy loaded page/module in Ionic 3

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I've implemented Ionic 3's lazy loading so it's great that my app doesn't have to load everything just to view the first page, but now I'm left with a small delay (on a web app this means downloading a ~15-20KB .js file) when accessing a page for the first time.

What I would like to do is to load "the next page" in the background once the current page has loaded. Most of the time it's known what page is "next", either because it's the "success" page of the one you're on, the next step in a sequence, or a detail page of items in a list etc.

Essentially I want to do something like what NavController does on push/insert/setRoot etc with a string, but without actually doing any nav.
There's `IonicPageModule.forChild()` but this doesn't accept a string.

I've seen I can use pre-loading of modules but this doesn't really provide much control of the order besides priority, and not really scalable to a larger app hence me wanting to rather manually control this but adding to each page a bit of code to load the next possible page/s.

Comment: As far as I know, priority is the only setting available for lazy loading. It would be great if they also added a "priorityorder" setting, so you could tell the app to load the "High" priority items according to the priorityorder, then the low priority items, again using the same order. BUT, even better would be to provide WAY more options..

Comment: Sorry, hit enter a little too fast. I'm sure much more control over lazy loading is coming. For now, it works ok, but I definitely see a need to have lazy loading available for say, a tab. When my user clicks on a tab, start loading the pages that they might use from that tab.

Comment: Yes exactly for something like that. Load the tab and first content quicker by not having to load every single tab, then if the user is just busy staring at the first tab and you're not doing anything you may as well start loading the other tabs so there isn't a lag when he hits another tab. Pre loading sort of does this but for the whole app and without "manual" control.